# how do you educate yourself to take better picture?

Tags: camera-settings

how do you educate yourself to take better pictures and on which camera.

Comment: Welcome to the stack exchange community, Rashk. Your first question isn't bad, but it's a tad broad. Are you trying to learn exposure? Composition? How to capitalize on certain camera functions in certain shooting situations (ex: AI Servo or BBF for sports)? **Please edit your question to provide more context and narrow it down...just a bit**. Thanks!

Comment: The problem isn't with your question — it's with what this site format can handle. From the site help, there's this suggestion: if you can imagine a book on the topic, the question is probably too broad. There are shelves and shelves of books about this. Can you narrow down to something a little more manageable?

Answer (score 2):

- Read the camera manual with camera in hand to practice taking pictures using each of the settings mentioned in the manual.
- Read about photography with camera in hand to practice taking pictures similar to those described.
- Read about art with camera in hand to practice taking pictures using art concepts described.
- Take a photography class. Practice taking pictures using the concepts taught in class.
- Take an art class. Practice taking pictures using the concepts taught in class.
- Critique photos, taken by yourself or others. Practice taking pictures based on results of critique.
- Socialize with people who also enjoy photography. Practice taking pictures using concepts or techniques discussed.
- **[Practice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Practice_(learning_method)) taking pictures.**

Answer (score 2):

Take a formal photography course that includes:

- A good foundation of the fundamentals of the mechanics or technical side of taking photographs.
- A brief survey of the history of the visual arts and how that history relates to composing photographs.
- Shooting all different kinds of photos, including kinds that you are *really interested in* and kinds that you *have zero interest in doing*. You might surprise yourself with what you find you like and/or are good at.
- Group critiques of everyones photos by the instructor(s) and other students. Not only will this help you to see the way others see your photos, but critiquing the photos of others will make your own photography stronger.

Here's [a good article from B&H](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/explora/photography/tips-and-solutions/photography-student-here-is-some-advice-from-teachers?utm_medium=Email%201692559&utm_campaign=Promotion&utm_source=WeeklySpecials%20180922&utm_content=Explora&utm_term=photography-student-here-is-some-advice-from-teachers&encEmail=9A81E78308B359D5315774A554B7405BBECFC55D76A50D0E5CACDD8D4B7D3B7A) that has some very good advice for how to get the most out of a formal photography course of study.

Answer (score -1):

Sites like creativelive.com and Lynda.com provide good training.  You can always attend a convention like WPPI in Vegas.